# Asynchronously accepting multiple client connections without impacting main thread

Tags: c#, multithreading, networking, tcp

I am implementing a multi-player game in C# and having seen all sorts of projects, from indie developers all the way to large studios struggle to patch networking into existing products in the past, have made the decision to get the networking aspect done first, and build the game on top of that.

I've so far gotten to the stage where my server can accept clients asynchronously, but I have a *strong* feeling that I've implemented the threading very badly. I think it is possible that I am misunderstanding and/or misusing async/await and Tasks, but having read documentation and similar questions I think I will need practical experience to get my head wrapped around the correct usage of these.

As a result, I am hoping that someone would be generous enough to look over my code and help push me onto the right track. I have excluded 'using' statements and the client code for the purposes of this question, however I can confirm the code does function correctly.

I am not too concerned about issues such as naming, and the fact that I have a bit too much code logic in the Main function right now -- these will be modified and extracted to more appropriate locations  respectively as the project progresses.

I have denoted lines I am particularly concerned about with `<---- THIS`

```
namespace Game_Server {
    class ServerMain {
        static void Main(string[] args) {
            Server server = new Server();

            server.Start().Start(); //<---- THIS

            while (true) {
                Console.WriteLine($"Number of connected users: {server.clients.Count}");
            }
        }
    }

    class Server {
        private TcpListener server { get; }
        private ConcurrentBag<TcpClient> _clients { get; set; }
        public List<TcpClient> clients { get {
                return _clients.ToList();
            } } //<---- THIS (This was just something I threw up to test my connection model, but any suggestions for handling a thread-safe list of clients would be greatly appreciated!)

        public Server() {
            server = new TcpListener(
                IPAddress.Parse("127.0.0.1"),
                6780
                );
            _clients = new ConcurrentBag<TcpClient>();
        }

        public Task Start() {
            server.Start();

            return new Task(async () => { // <---- THIS
                while (true) {
                    TcpClient client = await server.AcceptTcpClientAsync();
                    _clients.Add(client);
                    Console.WriteLine("Connection on port 6780 from client " + client.Client.RemoteEndPoint);
                }
            });
        }
    }
}
```

Additionally, my usage of any features in more recent C# iterations (C# 6 most notably) may not be up to scratch, so I'd appreciate any suggestions for making my code more condensed or 'modern'

I apologise if this question doesn't fit perfectly here -- I was concerned it was a bit too specific and if it is, please comment and I'll try to open it up a bit.

Comment: In my humble opinion, you were specific enough. Maybe a little too much, but that's alright. Any information that helps to understand the context is 100% helpful. You (literally) pointed out the areas of concern and everything seems to be well exlained. The code is working as you intend, I presume, and there's not much to say. Overall, in my opinion, a really well built question.

Answer (score 3):

Some quick remarks:

- Always add [access modifiers](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wxh6fsc7.aspx).
- You're not using `string[] args`, so remove it.
- I'm not a fan of private [properties](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w86s7x04.aspx), certainly not when they could be fields (and thus they should not have getters/setters). `private TcpListener server { get; }`, `private ConcurrentBag<TcpClient> _clients { get; set; }`
- Be consistent in naming: `_clients` starts with an underscore, which is a naming convention usually used for fields, but `server` doesn't start with an underscore.
- [Properties should be PascalCase](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/ms229043.aspx): `public List<TcpClient> clients`. I feel the same applies to private ones (previous remark).
- [No underscores in names](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229045.aspx) (with the exception of an underscore prefix for fields, of course): `Game_Server`.

Answer (score 2):

I see a couple of issues with the code, but I'm afraid this isn't exactly the answer that you're looking for. Hopefully someone a little smarter than myself swings by...

Anyway, in `Main`, you have this call.

> ```
>        Server server = new Server();
>
>       server.Start().Start();
> ```

But you start the server again in the `Start` method.

> ```
>    public Task Start() {
>        server.Start();
> ```

Which is hopelessly confusing because the second call is actually starting the `TcpListener`. Consider renaming your private field.

The chained `Start` calls in main are also confusing. I'd recommend an intermediate variable to clarify it.

```
Task task = server.Start();
task.Start();
```

The other thing I would like to mention is the hard coded IP address. `Server` should take that in as an argument in its constructor so that the ip can be stored in a configuration file and injected in at runtime.